# How to configure spring lemon to send emails via Sendgrid?

Tags: spring-lemon

I successfully sent emails via sendgrid's SMTP api, without change to my spring-lemon code. I did it just by configuring environment variables on cloudfoundry.

I would now like to use [sendgrid java library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java)

I then created the following class

```
    SendGrid sendgrid = new SendGrid('api_key');

SendGrid.Email email = new SendGrid.Email();
email.addTo("example@example.com");
email.setFrom("other@example.com");
email.setSubject("Hello World");
email.setText("My first email with SendGrid Java!");

try {
  SendGrid.Response response = sendgrid.send(email);
  System.out.println(response.getMessage());
}
catch (SendGridException e) {
  System.err.println(e);
}
```

How do I get spring-lemon to use this class instead of SmtpMailSender ?

Comment: The blueprint book says something about @ConditionalOnProperty but I don't know if it suits my particular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having your custom implementation of `MailSender`, and configuring that as a bean should suppress Spring Lemon's `SmtpMailSender` configuration, because Spring Lemon's `MailConfiguration` class is annotated with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(MailSender.class)`. (Refer page 79 of the blueprint book - *Allowing developers to provide their implementations*)

`@ConditionalOnMissingBean` is notorious, but I had tested it to be working in this case.

Comment: I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: Should it implement `org.springframework.mail.MailSender` or `com.naturalprogrammer.spring.lemon.mail.MailSender` ?

Comment: com.naturalprogrammer.spring.lemon.mail.MailSender

Comment: It worked !. I've created a MailSender implementation, and declared it as a `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` class. But one thing odd is that it's also trying to run while running in development environment, locally.

Comment: Yes, because now Spring Lemon has backed away. To use the `MockMailSender`, you can follow the same technique as used in Spring Lemon - see the `MailConfiguration` class and the blueprint book for details.